# Can't install package from pip with python 3.6 virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pkg-config

I created a virtual environment for python 3.6 and I tried to install `crc16` package. I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6m
```

I tried to fix it using

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/python3.6/binaries/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

and I tested it using

```
$ pkg-config --libs python3
-L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.6m
```

but unluckily it continues to not work.

Python 3.6 is installed in a custom prefix using `make install DESTDIR=/path/to/destdir`